# Understand decorators on Flask-HTTPAuth

Tags: flask, flask-httpauth

I want to understand how and when @auth.verify_password decorator is used on this program. 
If i navigate to route http://127.0.0.1:5000, I understand that I need to passed in a username and a password and @auth.login_required will verify it, but where does @auth.verify_password comes in?

Does @auth.login_required calls it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

users = {
    "john": generate_password_hash("hello"),
    "susan": generate_password_hash("bye")
}


@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    if username in users:
        return check_password_hash(users.get(username), password)
    return False


@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_httpauth.HTTPBasicAuth.verify_password):

> **verify_password(verify_password_callback)**
>
> If defined, this callback
>   function will be called by the framework to verify that the username
>   and password combination provided by the client are valid. The
>   callback function takes two arguments, the username and the password
>   and must return True or False.

So you basically provide the function so your program is able to verify the credentials supplied by the user.

The `login_required` decorator protects the route by reading the authentication credentials provided by the user and passing them to your `verify_password` function to be verified.